# Algorithm for function optimization using trust region method

Tags: c, algorithm, matlab, math, mathematical-optimization

We are currently trying to port existing trust-region algorithm from MATLAB to C or C++ (part of BS degree work). The problem is the device - TMS320f28335, so most of the higher level libraries are out of the question. So far we looked at [dlib optmization](http://dlib.net/optimization.html), but I'm not sure that this can be compiled to an actual device using Composer Studio. I'm not sure about Ceres. Hardware will arrive in two weeks so our actual experience is quite limited at this point.

Function is:

```
F = sum ( (X(1)*sin(X(2)*T (i)+ X(3)) - Y(i))^2 ) where i=0..N
T and Y are the dot's coordinates for sinusoidal sampled signal. X(1..3) are unknowns.
```

Currently we use MatLab [fit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) for experimentation and visualization, but that obviously wouldn't do for real hardware.

Example:
[image: Approximation] where blue line is approximation using MatLab.

I tried to google relentlessly, but few libraries or source files showed up. I'm pretty sure that Ceres or ALGLIB can't be compiled under target platform. So any advice where to look next would be quite welcome.

P.S. This is actually for a colleague of mine, who doesn't use stack-exchange, so additional questions are welcome. I'm sorry if question sounds incorrectly, because my lack of knowledge on a subject.

Comment: to generate the figure you just need a fft

Comment: I checked "MATLAB Coder" supported functions, but the `fit` function is not listed: http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--categorical-list.html.. Too bad, that would have been easy :)

Comment: If you plan to use this for real-time digital signal processing, you won't be able to use the same approximation approach anyway; e.g. if you only have the first four sample points, you won't have reached the maximum anyway.  Can you adapt the equation itself as a solution, or is that just an example that might radically change?

Comment: @matt-jordan can you elaborate on "adapt the equation" part?  Sample points are actually "capturing windows" so it will be [0,1000) [1000, 2000) [2000, 3000)... so results are more like snapshots during some time.

Comment: I didn't realize you were using "capturing windows" to limit the view, that clears up my confusion; your equation seemed to use i=0..N for N total sample points, rather than a capturing window of size N.

Comment: @matt-jordan yes - I talked a bit with colleague about what happens if signal form changes during "window" - for now we think that signal doesn't change during window.  Current approach is to use FFT to find starting points and then use them with Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm.